# Integrate Facebook login with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook-login

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.3 and I want to integrate Facebook login with Cake's Auth component.

I've tried http://www.idiotminds.com/login-with-facebook-using-php-sdk-in-cakephp/ and https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin but both didn't work for me.

I want to allow users to login to our site using their Facebook account and save their public info to our database.

**EDIT:**

For example, for **https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin**, as far as I've done: it now logs user in and saves facebook_id to my users database table. But I can't get it to save the other facebook user infomation.

I've tried to put a test username like:

```
$this->authUser[$this->User->alias][$this->modelFields['username']] = 'facebk_uname';
```

and confirmed this is the right variable to save to but how to get the facebook username doesn't seem to be documented on this plugin. I've tried to debug **$this->me** and **$Auth** everytime a new record is saved but it's always null.
How should I retrieve the fb user's profile from **__syncFacebookUser function** on **ConnectComponent.php**?

Comment: You do realize that telling other programmers something along the lines of `but both didn't work for me` is the same as banging on your keyboard randomly? Also, if I take the title of your question, highlight it with my mouse, press right click and select `Search google for...` - I get numerous results. Even on StackOverflow. Don't be lazy, research and make use of trial and error.

Comment: i get what you're saying @N.B. but I've been integrating both for a week now and I'm not getting anywhere. other results are mostly with cake 1.3 or other old versions. Hope you understand where I'm coming from.

Comment: Then show what you have tried and what you get, include the code, errors, failures, expectations and the whole 9 yards.

Comment: Okay. I edited my question @N.B. Is that a bit helpful now?